# Where does this field get its value?

Tags: custom-field, options

I've inherited maintenance of a wordpress site with a custom template. I'm trying to change the value of a phone number that is displayed throughout the site. I've found the field by looking in the template php files here:

```
<a href="tel:<?php the_field('phone_number', 'option'); ?>"><strong>Phone:</strong>  <?php the_field('phone_number', 'option'); ?></a>
```

I tried editing the page to see if there's a box where I can fill this in, but I can't find it anywhere.

Is there some sort of global menu for these types of fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That clearly is a plugin field of "Advanced Custom Fields".

The function:

```
the_field();
```

is one of the utility functions of the plugin. The purpose of "Advanced Custom Fields" is to enable users with less coding-knowledge to add custom fields to a theme/template.

So, in order to reverse engineer the whole thing, you propably need to install and activate "ACF" (very often used as an abbreviation for Advanced Custom Fields).

Activate it, and see what happens. In case your installation is missing the necessary data for the plugin, you might have to add them via ACF in the backend.

Try to find the field in the backend, which says "phone_number" it should be there, if it is not existent - create it.

Here is the [plugin's website](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) and here the [documentation of the field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/).

Comment: This helped me track it down. It was pulling this from the "phone number" field in "theme options". If anyone else is curious, you can tell because of the 'option' parameter. There's a list in the link provided above that tells you where the field is coming from.

Comment: Glad I could help, thanks for accepting.